# Best way to show a different Decimal Precision when TextBox is focused or not?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have control, that is used by others. It has a TexBox that is binding to a decimal value. And since the Precision can vary, I am using a DependencyProperty and MultiBinding to specify it.
When the TextBox is not focused the number should be displayed with the specified Precision, but when it is focused the full number should be displayed.

Example:

- Precision: 2
- User Input: 29.333
- TextBox not focused should show: 29.33
- TextBox focused should show: 29.333

I have accomplished this by using a IMultibindingConverter, and the IsFocused property. But I don't know if this is the best approach.

**My TexBox is defined like this**

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
        <conv:ValuePrecisionConverter x:Key="ValuePrecisionConverter" />        
    </UserControl.Resources>
       <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox">
                 <TextBox.Text>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValuePrecisionConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay"
     NotifyOnValidationError="true">
                     <Binding ElementName="parent" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
                     <Binding ElementName="parent" Path="Precision"/>
                     <Binding ElementName="parent" Path="AdditionalFormatting"/>
                     <Binding ElementName="myTextBox" Path="IsFocused" Mode="OneWay"/>
                     </MultiBinding>
                 </TextBox.Text>           
       </TextBox>
```

My **ValuePrecisionConver** is defined like this:

```
 public class ValuePrecisionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double? value = null;
            converter = null;

            value = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
            precision = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
            //Other code with 3rd parameter

            if (values.Count() > 3)
            {
                bool isFocused = System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[3]);

                if (isFocused)
                    return value.ToString();
            }

           /*Here I do the formating with the given precision*/
           return formattedValue;
        }


}
```

Is this the best way to accomplish what I need? Is it ok to use the IsFocused property like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with thisss.

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value, StringFormat=n2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                 </Trigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: The Format of my Value has different Precisions, it depends on the person using my control. And additionally it may have some special formatting added. How do I accomplish that with your suggestion?

Comment: You can binding your StringFormat with a dynamic value: StringFormat={Binding ...} or StringFormat={StaticResource ...} . More info StringFormat in   http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to go for Event Trigger with PreviewGotKeyboardFocus and PreviewLostKeyboardFocus... Set the value with a converter.. No need of MuiltBinding here...

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean with setting the value with a converter. My precision depends on the Value of my DependencyProperty Precision. And also I have to apply some custom formatting with AdditionalFormatting (which is another dependency property). How would accomplish that?